# Core Data: when to enable lightweight migrations?

Tags: ios, core-data, versioning, data-modeling, core-data-migration

Should I add a model version and enable lightweight versioning of `Core Data` from the first version of the app, or it can be done in a later app update if needed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must I enable versioning in my first release in order to use lightweight migration in subsequent releases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029703/must-i-enable-versioning-in-my-first-release-in-order-to-use-lightweight-migrati)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a later App update.
The key point to remember is that Any new Core Data model can be automatically inferred from existing model or not.

Lightweight migrations can handle the following changes:

- Adding or removing an entity, attribute, or relationship
- Making an attribute non-optional with a default value
- Making a non-optional attribute optional
- Renaming an entity or attribute using a renaming identifier

For anything else you need manual migration.

Comment: And is it needed to set something from the beggining in case you may need a manual or any kind of migration later?

Comment: No, you can set it up later.

Comment: You only need manual migration if a mapping model can't handle the changes.